# Matlab - Why sometimes xslread doesn't let use a number as a sheet argument?

Tags: excel, matlab

I want to read an excel file with 10 sheets with matlab with the xlsread function like this:

```
SPLByFrequency = zeros(173, 10);
for i = 1:10
    rawData = xlsread('mediciones', i);
    SPLByFrequency(:, i) = rawData(84:256, 3);
end
```

It's not the first time I read excel sheets using a number as argument and I've never had any problem but this time it doesn't let me do it and I get this error:

```
Error using xlsread (line 207)
In basic mode, sheet argument must be a string.

Error in TareaB53 (line 11)
    rawData = xlsread('mediciones', i);
```

I haven't been able to change this 'basic' mode and doing some debugging I've found that, strangely enough, xlsread('mediciones', 1) works but it doesn't work with any other number.

Doing some research I've found there is a way to escape from this problem by using xlsinfo to get the sheet names and then use the sheet strings as an argument but I don't understand why I couldn't do it simply directly with a number, why I can do it just with the number 1 or why it suddenly doesn't work while I've always been doing it with a number as an argument.

Is there a way to solve this and use directly a number as a sheet argument?

## Edit - Summary and new information

If you don't have **Excel for Windows** installed, `xlsread` operates in basic mode so you cannot use a number for the sheet argument.

Therefore, for portability, it would be better to use `xlsinfo` to get the sheet strings.

For some reason, even if it seems it isn't supposed to, (for me) it worked on OS X 10.9. However, it doesn't work anymore on OS X 10.11 (I have Matlab release 2012a).

Comment: From the Matlab doc: `basic mode is the default for computers without Excel for Windows.`. Usually `basic` is a flag _off_ by default, which you can activate. But if Excel (windows) is **not installed** on your computer the flag will be enforced anyway and you will have to specify the sheet number as a string. I don't know if the fact that the index `1` works is a glitch or simply `xlsread` invalidating the input and using a default value (the first sheet), but your program will be more robust (and portable) if you make the effort to read the sheet names and refer to them as string.

Comment: @Hoki I'm actually using a mac and I do have Excel installed (should I edit the post to add this info? I'm a newbie here). You know a way of setting the flag off? I haven't been able to find how to. I've tried using `''` for the mode argument but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you need **Excel for Windows**, otherwise you're in basic mode. Here's the relevant extract from the documentation:

> `num = xlsread(filename)` reads data from the first worksheet in the
>   Microsoft® Excel® spreadsheet file named `filename` and returns the
>   numeric data in array `num`.
>
> On Windows® systems with Microsoft Excel software, xlsread reads any
>   file format recognized by your version of Excel.
>
> If your system does not have Excel for Windows, xlsread operates in
>   basic import mode, and reads only XLS, XLSX, XLSM, XLTX, and XLTM
>   files.

I suspect it worked before because you used it on a Windows PC, not a Mac.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info. However, I used it before on the same Mac, where it worked. Anyway, I have just realised that the last time I tried it and worked, I had an older version of the OS so that may be the cause that it doesn't remain as before...